# Exporting RDLC on letter head

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I have a requirement to export RDLC report into PDF, it should also contain letter head of the company in background. Problem I see is that RDLC has a header, body and footer, how do we apply common image background? Any idea to this issue?

Comment: We had a similar issue with our report generator (MS Access, not RDLC), and solved it by (1) creating the PDF without letterhead and then (2) using PDFSharp to merge the resulting PDF with a letterhead PDF. Something like this might work for your use case as well.

Comment: Do you have the code handy to marge those PDFs? It will be a great help.

Comment: Sure, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

*(Posted as an answer, since it's too long for a comment.)*

I don't know of a method to add a page background directly in an RDLC. However, we had a similar issue with our report generator (MS Access, not RDLC), and solved it by (1) creating the PDF without letterhead and then (2) using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net) to merge the resulting PDF with a letterhead ("background") PDF. Something like this might work for your use case as well.

We use the following code:

```
public static void AddBackground(string source, string background, string result)
{
    using (var formBackground = XPdfForm.FromFile(background))
    using (var pdf = PdfReader.Open(source, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
    {
        foreach (var page in pdf.Pages.Cast<PdfPage>())
        {
            var xg = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
            xg.DrawImage(formBackground, 0, 0);

            if (formBackground.PageIndex < formBackground.PageCount - 1)
            {
                formBackground.PageIndex += 1;
            }
        }

        pdf.Save(result);
    }
}
```

All parameters are paths to the respective PDF files. If the background PDF has less pages than the source PDF, then the last page of the background PDF is added to all remaining source PDF pages. It is useful if your first page has a different background than all remaining pages, you just need a 2-page background PDF for that.